# constant signal strength of a 802.11 probe request

Tags: wifi, probe

In a small test scenario I'm measuring the signal strength at the AP.
Do the client smartphones keep a constant signal strength for probe
requests or are there reasons they are varying it?

thanks in advance
Wolfgang R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question was not clear .Still below are the points i can tell from WLAN Technology.

1. In WLAN signal strength or RSSI  keeps on varying as the medium is wireless.
2. Clients(Ex: Smart Phones) get RSSI of AP from AP's Beacon or any packets coming from AP.So depending on medium ,how that packet came to client ,client determines the RSSI and keep it for that time.
3. So coming to your question, there is no chance client gets constant RSSI/Signal Strength.

Comment: Hi  Banmdeb

a bit background here. I've to do a small experiment to test
localization of smartphone clients by having a network of
APs in that area.

I'm aware that trilateration from the signal strength of 
the probe requests is not a good approach (even a very bad one). 
But this approach is given in my case.

What I want to know is that the smartphone emits a probe
request at its Tx output at a constants signal strength or not.
Or if e.g. battery status is low the emitted signal is
of lower power? I assume the Tx signal has a constant signal strength.

Comment: @WolfgangR. Probe Request is sent in constant Tx power if phone has  enough battery power. But in general if battery is low ,Tx Power is reduced. But all these are implementation dependent .
**TX max Power should be less than max allowed power of regulatory domain**

Comment: Hi Bamdeb, thanks that was the info I was looking for.